# Wordpress contact form 7 dynamic emails

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help with Contact Form 7. I've got page with people contacts, user picks the one whom he like to contact, and can contact him. I'm trying to create modal with bootstrap, so that on Contact with Someone click modal pops up with CF7 form. But how can i change email whom to send email depending on which person he clicks? I don't want that people emails would be visible. I can't find information about that in CF7. This is my modal with cf7 shortcode:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="write-letter-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Susisiekite</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="79564" title="Įmonės kontaktų forma"]' ); ?>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Email will be send to person who fill that form and enter email id.

Comment: I want that email would be disabled, and i could change it by javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by inserting a form tag such as:
For Example:

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                "Sales|sales@example.com"
                "Support|support@example.com"]
```

You can read more [SELECTABLE RECIPIENT WITH PIPES](http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/)